# div elements in list-group that go line

Tags: javascript, html, angular, drop-down-menu, html-lists

I don't know why when I have the second selection in the `div` it makes me do it in line. I would like (see image) that she would go side by side instead.
[image: Text]

I added the comment `<!-- -->` in the part to be moved.

```html
<div class="card-body">

            <ul class="list-group">

                <li class="list-group-item">
                    <tr *ngFor="let row of matrix; index as r">
                        <td *ngFor="let columns of row; index as c">
                    <tr *ngIf="r === 1">
                        <td *ngIf="c === 0">
                            <strong>Efficacia:</strong><br>
                            <select [(ngModel)]="scelta">
                                <option value="yes">è più importante di</option>
                                <option value="no">è meno importante di</option>
                            </select>
                            modicità di costo. Di quanto?

                            <!--THIS MUST GO TO THE RIGHT INSTEAD OF DOWN-->
                            <div *ngIf="scelta === 'yes'">
                                <select [(ngModel)]="oggetto[r][c]" (change)="onSelectChange(r,c)">
                                    <option [ngValue]="a.num" *ngFor="let a of arrayComparazioneFrazioni">
                                        {{a.char}}
                                    </option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div *ngIf="scelta === 'no'">
                                <select [(ngModel)]="oggetto[r][c]" (change)="onSelectChange(r,c)">
                                    <option [ngValue]="a.num" *ngFor="let a of arrayComparazioneInteri">
                                        {{a.char}}
                                    </option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <!-- END -->

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                </li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if I have understood correctly, your problem can be solved by changing the `display` property of your `div`. By default, `div` is set to `display: block;`. You can change it to `display: inline-block;` to show it on the same line. Check out the code below:

#### Edit

You can apply it to the other div as well. Better to create a class and set these styles to that class.

#### Edit 2

You can simply use the bootstrap class `d-inline-block` to make it work! (demonstrated on the second `div`.)

```html
<div class="card-body">

            <ul class="list-group">

                <li class="list-group-item">
                    <tr *ngFor="let row of matrix; index as r">
                        <td *ngFor="let columns of row; index as c">
                    <tr *ngIf="r === 1">
                        <td *ngIf="c === 0">
                            <strong>Efficacia:</strong><br>
                            <select [(ngModel)]="scelta">
                                <option value="yes">è più importante di</option>
                                <option value="no">è meno importante di</option>
                            </select>
                            modicità di costo. Di quanto?

                            <!--THIS MUST GO TO THE RIGHT INSTEAD OF DOWN-->
                            <div *ngIf="scelta === 'yes'" style="display: inline-block;">
                                <select [(ngModel)]="oggetto[r][c]" (change)="onSelectChange(r,c)">
                                    <option [ngValue]="a.num" *ngFor="let a of arrayComparazioneFrazioni">
                                        {{a.char}}
                                    </option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div *ngIf="scelta === 'no'" class="d-inline-block">
                                <select [(ngModel)]="oggetto[r][c]" (change)="onSelectChange(r,c)">
                                    <option [ngValue]="a.num" *ngFor="let a of arrayComparazioneInteri">
                                        {{a.char}}
                                    </option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <!-- END -->

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                </li>
```